# AJAX form rendering is breaking with Puma Parse error

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-5, puma, parse-error

For one of my features, AJAX form data rendering is breaking in local environment with this error,

```
HTTP Parse error, malformed request():#<Puma::HttpParseError:Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.>
```

Record gets inserted successfully but while returning back with default back URL, its failing locally.

On QA server it's working fine.

I checked few solutions but none of them worked.

Can anyone please suggest ?

Thanks.